# Mathematical (simple?) vs physical pendulums

Tags: terminology, definition, oscillators

I've looked long and hard for what a [mathematical pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)) is but no site clearly has the name "mathematical" pendulum but it's all over the book "Problems in General Physics" by I.E. Irodov .

Reading a few sites I get the impression that mathematical and simple pendulums are the same thing.

Is this true?

Comment: If its terminology only used in that one book, surely the book defines what it means (probably very early on?)

Comment: Possibly means an ideal pendulum with no friction or drag. But I agree - if you have only found the term used in one book then you should look for a definition in that book.

Comment: The terminology is not important. All that matters is the equation describing the pendulum.

Comment: My guess would be that one is the mathematical model given to the physical device (pendulum)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s just a translation issue from common Russian terminology into English terminology. While the literal translation of “математический маятник” is “mathematical pendulum,” the terminologically correct translation is simply “pendulum”.

Comment: The terminology is also used in German (where the mathematical pendulum is a point mass suspended by a weightless bar, contrasting with the physical pendulum, which is a rigid body swinging around a pivot point).